# Using FBX SDK, how to extract multiple animations in a single fbx file?

Tags: graphics, computer-science, game-engine, game-development

I have successfully imported single animation with FBX SDK using the method
`FBXNode->EvaluateGlobalTransform(time)`. But the problem is that you don't specify which FBXAnimStack to use in this method. I think the method just use the first animation stack by default. So for a FBX file containing multiple animations, how can I import all of them?

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate all FbxAnimLayers, then iterate each member as an FbxAnimStack,
Then for every node/property in your scene you can grab the FbxAnimCurve that is modified in the given AnimStack. Then, evaluate that over time.